# Extensible layout components in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am creating an application in nextjs. I understand that I can generate a layout like the example given in the docs

```
import Navbar from './navbar'
import Footer from './footer'

export default function Layout({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <Navbar />
      <main>{children}</main>
      <Footer />
    </>
  )
}
```

However, I would like to change the contents of the `Navbar` on a per page basis.

```
export default function ListPage() {
  return {
    /** I want to add a secondary nav to the Navbar on this page */
    <>
      <Navbar><MySecondaryNav></Navbar>
      ....
    </>
  }
}

export default function ClientPage() {
  return {
    /** I want to add a a different secondary nav to the Navbar on this page */
    <>
      <Navbar><ClientNavbar></Navbar>
      ....
    </>
  }
}
```

I also need the markup to be rendered server-side. Is it possible to achieve this in nextjs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can!

You could use useRouter and then depending on the path render the correct component in NavBar

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
const router = useRouter();
```

now you should have access to **router.pathname**, depending on the pathname just render the correct component inside NavBar

@Edit - SSR solution

If you want this SSR, then this is how you do it

in your **_app.tsx/jsx** you can use [getServerSideProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props) and then get directly **resolvedUrl**

```
export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {

  return (
    <Layout {...pageProps}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </Layout>
  );
}
export async function getServerSideProps({{req, res, resolvedUrl}) {

  return { props: { resolvedUrl } }
}
```

At this point you should be receiving resolvedUrl and based on that render the required component.

If this wont work for you we might need to setup a codesandbox

Comment: I should have mentioned, I want the markup rendered server side

Comment: thank you, passing the necessary data through pageProps was the solution for me